# How can I trigger spinner event when on click?

Tags: java, adapter, android-spinner

I followed some examples. they are introducing the way like below. but when I tried that, I got this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
    at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:1224)
    at com.jakchang.savelocation.databinding.ActivityViewmemoBindingImpl.executeBindings(ActivityViewmemoBindingImpl.java:174)
```

I just followed examples, but it's not working to me.

*need help..thanks in advance*

```
 resList = res.getStringArray(R.array.font_spinner);

    SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,resList);
        binding.fontlist.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        binding.fontlist.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item : "+binding.fontlist.getItemAtPosition(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you are binding resList with your spinner and trying to fetch data from fontlist.

Comment: I editted about the resList

Comment: what's exactly not working in this ?

Comment: when I click some item, then that error is occured.

Comment: what are you trying to do. Working with spinner then get the details of selected item ?

Comment: what you have posted in your question as error is not present in the code that you posted

Comment: No.. there is an error. when I exclude above codes, there is no error. but when I try attach onClickListener at spinner, the error occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet isn't complete but I tried to implement it in my own activity, so check the following code and compare it with your solution. I think it should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.font_spinner));
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item : "+ spinner.getItemAtPosition(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

First you need to get the view and store it in a class variable with the `findViewById(R.id.spinner)` of course you have to set the id in the xml file. Next in the ArrayAdapter use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` just to keep it simple. And finally set the adapter and the listener on the **spinner** object.

Comment: thank u!! it's working. can I get the why my code is not working?

Comment: I found that the difference is android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item in your code, and my code is R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item. haha.... I think there is some difference.